# I wish to append two query together , so that all fields in query one and query two appear in my union query

Tags: ms-access

### Querying two tables and appending the results

I am trying to combine the results from [Sales query] and [production query] using a union all statement. However, when I run the query, some of the fields are omitted. How can I append both queries and ensure that all the fields are included in the result set? Below is the SQL Statement i wrote.

[Production Query]

```sql
SELECT Production.Date, Production.[Supplier/Demander], Item.Item, Item.Color, Production.[Opening BAL], Production.[In], Production.[Adj(+)], Production.[Total IN], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE 
FROM Customers INNER JOIN ((Item INNER JOIN Production ON Item.[Item ID] = Production.[Item ID]) INNER JOIN Sales ON Item.[Item ID] = Sales.[Item ID]) ON Customers.Code = Sales.Code 
GROUP BY Production.Date, Production.[Supplier/Demander], Item.Item, Item.Color, Production.[Opening BAL], Production.[In], Production.[Adj(+)], Production.[Total IN], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE;
```

[Sales Query]

```sql
SELECT Sales.Date, Sales.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, Sales.Out, Sales.[Adj(-)], Sales.[Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE 
FROM Customers INNER JOIN ((Item INNER JOIN Production ON Item.[Item ID] = Production.[Item ID]) INNER JOIN Sales ON Item.[Item ID] = Sales.[Item ID]) ON Customers.Code = Sales.Code 
GROUP BY Sales.Date, Sales.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, Sales.Out, Sales.[Adj(-)], Sales.[Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE;
```

Comment: Unless you show us the SQL that you are using, nobody can help you. Please modify your question to include the raw data from the two tables as text (not an image), the SQL of the query that you have and what it produces, and the output that you would like/are expecting.

Comment: This is SQL for [Production Query] SELECT Production.Date, Production.[Supplier/Demander], Item.Item, Item.Color, Production.[Opening BAL], Production.[In], Production.[Adj(+)], Production.[Total IN], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE
FROM Customers INNER JOIN ((Item INNER JOIN Production ON Item.[Item ID] = Production.[Item ID]) INNER JOIN Sales ON Item.[Item ID] = Sales.[Item ID]) ON Customers.Code = Sales.Code
GROUP BY Production.Date, Production.[Supplier/Demander], Item.Item, Item.Color, Production.[Opening BAL], Production.[In], Production.[Adj(+)], Production.[Total IN], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE;

Comment: This is SQL for [Sales Query] SELECT Sales.Date, Sales.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, Sales.Out, Sales.[Adj(-)], Sales.[Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE
FROM Customers INNER JOIN ((Item INNER JOIN Production ON Item.[Item ID] = Production.[Item ID]) INNER JOIN Sales ON Item.[Item ID] = Sales.[Item ID]) ON Customers.Code = Sales.Code
GROUP BY Sales.Date, Sales.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, Sales.Out, Sales.[Adj(-)], Sales.[Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE;

Answer (score 1):

Count and data type of the fields of the two queries must be an exact match, like:

[Production Query]

```sql
SELECT Production.Date, Production.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, Production.[Opening BAL], Production.[In], 0 As [Out], Production.[Adj(+)], Production.[Total IN], 0 As [Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE
```

[Sales Query]

```sql
SELECT Sales.Date, Sales.[Supplier/Demander], Customers.Customer, Item.Item, Item.Color, 0 As [Opening BAL], 0 As [In], Sales.Out, Sales.[Adj(-)], 0 As [Total In], Sales.[Total Out], Item.Grade, Item.TYPE
```